# How to manage searching through a large amount of text files

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a large amount of IRC logs (~1000 text files), and the amount of log files in climbing every day. I would like to build a tool to allow me to effectively search the files.

Would the best solution be to execute a grep command from php?

I am trying to make this fast. Obviously loading the data into a MYSQL table would be great, however the logs from the current day are constantly being written to and this would mean they would need constant SQL's being made to sync the data from the text files.

Comment: You could write today's log to a temporary file and move it to the database every day.

Comment: @Pietu1998 but then that means I can't search today's data, which I have needed to do before.

Comment: You could search both the database and the temporary file. One file to search/grep through is manageable.

Comment: @Pietu1998 yes I guess that would work.

Comment: might take a look at logstash

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to learn the most efficient technique. The best practices for that, i have ever seen is linux-console bash-script(default is bash)

Its very easy to query files with native functions.

For example;
[grep](http://ss64.com/bash/grep.html) search a string throughout file/s. there are high amount of options for native functions. All the console can use regular expressions. to find files, moving them, queering their content etc.

EDIT;

- If you have mac. It can run in terminal.
- If pc, a virtual terminal with shared folders, slow but works.
- But the best is just a linux-console with bash-shell.
- Beacuse of being an OS, file operations are highly efficient.
- And it can execute phps files in the middle of a operation.

Answer (score 0):

How about making use of more than one of the CPU cores in your machine and searching them all in parallel using GNU Parallel - [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html).

For example:

```
parallel -n 16 grep -H "some pattern" ::: *.log
```

will start, and keep running in parallel, as many `grep`s as you have cores in your CPU passing a maximum of 16 files to each `grep` to search in.